# Error while reading file with special characters from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

While reading file name from the S3 Bucket we are getting below exception.
The filename format has extra special characters.

Eg: input%2B0%2B0000000036.json , partition%3D0/input%2B0%2B0000000037.json

Exception:
"message": "An exception of type Exception occurred. Arguments:('Failure while get file from S3 - An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.',)",

Please help us in resolving this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried requesting the url decoded version? `input+0+0000000036.json`

Answer (score 1):

You have to decode your url since it contains special characters.

```
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus
result = unquote_plus('input%2B0%2B0000000036.json')
print(result)
```